# Why are all weights set to zero when linking my armature to my character with automatic weights?

Tags: armature, weight-painting

I'm trying to animate my golem and to do this I obviously created an armature. The problem is when I link my armature to the golem with the automatic weight settings, it sets the weight to 0 (blue) everywhere.

I think it's because my golem is a little like Rayman in style (I mean he has no real limbs and is just some rock animated together but not touching each other).

I tried to paint it in weight paint mode but it's damn long and kinda frustrating because some parts are really close to each other and I can't really paint where I want exactly.

Here is my golem:

[image]

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ok after checking several options i figured out that if i link my armature object by object it s automatically weight painted , but it's laggy and i wonder why .... Maybe because i ve got to many faces ?

Comment: too hard to know what's your problem if you don't share the object

Comment: Ok here is a link to download my blend file : https://www.transfernow.net/files/?utm_source=21bky1y8ybec&utm_medium=&utm_content=fr

the only problem now is that it's laggy and it's impossible to do correct key frames with those lags.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your bones have the checkbox marked: DEFORMER in the properties of the bone. Also, when you ctrl+P make sure you choose with "automatic weights". If you see no vertex assigned colors, chances are your armature bones are not setup to deform.